# OleVariant in Delphi Copy by value or References?

Tags: delphi

I have a code like this:

```
function Test: OleVariant;
var
   r: OleVariant;
begin
   r := VarArrayCreate([0, 100], varVariant);
   // some other code goes here
   Result := r; // does this perform deep or shadow copy?
end;
```

So the question is, for OleVariant types,  the assignment operation copies the value or reference?

Does it depend on the OleVariant types?

Comment: Did you try `var pOleVariant : ^OleVariant;`

Comment: It depends. Do you just want to know the answer for this variant, or do you want to understand it for all different types?

Comment: yes, I want to know different types. :)

Comment: You need to make these things clear in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OleVariant` is a wrapper for the Win32 OLE [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627.aspx) structure.  Assignments of `VARIANT` data is **always** deep, as `VARIANT` has no concept of any reference-counted data other than interfaces (in which case, assignments increment the reference count).  Arrays inside of `VARIANT` are implemented using the [`SAFEARRAY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482.aspx) structure, which is not reference counted, thus must be deep-copied (if the array holds interface pointers, their reference counts are incremented).

BTW, `VarArrayCreate()` returns a Delphi `Variant`, not an `OleVariant`.  Assigning a `Variant` to an `OleVariant` converts the data into an OLE-compatible format that the Win32 `VARIANT` structure supports, which includes using `SAFEARRAY` for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

A simple test like this

```
function Test: OleVariant;
var
   r: OleVariant;
begin
   r := VarArrayCreate([0, 100], varVariant);
   // some other code goes here
   r[1] := 'Deep';
   Result := r; // does this perform deep or shadow copy?
   r[1] := 'Shallow'
end;

procedure TForm10.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(Test[1]);
end;
```

gives the answer *Deep*

There was some speculation in the comments, that the test case could be wrong because of some copy-on-write functionality triggered by the assignment `r[1] := 'Deep';`. I can confirm that an assignment of a variant array of variant (even with unassigned elements) is done as a deep copy, no cow here.

Comment: It doesn't actually give the answer: it's possible for arrays to be implemented as copy-on-write, where `Result := r` would perform a shallow copy, but the assignment to `r[1]` would force a deep copy. (I don't think that really happens for variant arrays, but it does happen for some of Delphi's other types with special language support, so you'd need to rule it out.)

Comment: @hvd I can assure you that an assignment of a variant array of variant (even with unassigned elements) is done with a deep copy, no cow here.

Comment: I'm already pretty sure of that, my point is that your answer doesn't sufficiently demonstrate it IMO.

Comment: @hvd: does it actually matter? The result is the same.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes, it matters. If this logic is not disputed here, then if some other question asks about a different implementation of arrays that does use COW, then someone wanting to answer might be mislead by this one's incorrect line of reasoning into posting a factually incorrect answer. But since the edit drawing attention to the potential problem, I think it is fine now.